# Solving a simple puzzle in prolog

Tags: c, algorithm, recursion, prolog

I solved a puzzle in C and tried to do the same in Prolog but i'm having some trouble expressing the facts and goals in this language.

The very simplified version of the problem is this: there's two levers in a room. Each lever control a mechanism that can move either forward or backward in four different positions (which i noted 0, 1, 2 or 3). If you move a mechanism four times in the same direction, it'll be in the same position as before.

The lever n°1 move the mechanism n°1 two positions forward.
The lever n°2 move the mechanism n°2 one position forward.

Initially, the mechanism n°1 is in position 2 and the mechanism n°2 is in position 1.
The problem is to find the quickest way to move both mechanisms in position 0 and get the sequence of lever that lead to each solution.

Of course here the problem is trivial and you only need to pull the lever n°1 one time and the lever n°2 three times to have a solution.

Here's a simple code in C which gives the sequence of lever to pull to solve this problem by pulling less than 5 levers:

```
int pos1 = 2, pos2 = 1;

int main()
{
    resolve(0,5);
    return 0;
}

void lever1(){
    pos1 = (pos1 + 2) % 4;
}

void undolever1(){
    pos1 = (pos1 - 2) % 4;
}

void lever2(){
    pos2 = (pos2 + 1) % 4;
}

void undolever2(){
    pos2 = (pos2 - 1) % 4;
}

void resolve(l, k){
    if(k == 0){
        return;
    }
    if(pos1 == 0 && pos2 == 0){
        printf("Solution: %d\n", l);
        return;
    }
    if(k>0){
        k--;
        lever1();
        resolve(l*10+1,k);
        undolever1();
        lever2();
        resolve(l*10+2,k);
        undolever2();
    }
}
```

My code in Prolog looks like this so far:

```
lever(l1).
lever(l2).

mechanism(m1).
mechanism(m2).

position(m1,2).
position(m2,1).

pullL1() :- position(m1, mod(position(m1,X)+2,4)).
pullL2() :- position(m2, mod(position(m2,X)+1,4)).

solve(k) :- solve_(k, []).
solve_(0, r) :- !, postion(m1, p1), postion(m2, p2), p1 == 0, p2 == 0.
solve_(k, r) :- k > 0, pullL1(), k1 is k - 1, append(r, [1], r1), solve_(k1, r1).
solve_(k, r) :- k > 0, pullL2(), k1 is k - 1, append(r, [2], r2), solve_(k1, r2).
```

I'm pretty sure there's multiple problems in this code but I'm not sure how to fix it.
Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Can you *identify* (if not fix) any of the multiple problems with this code?

Comment: Welcome to SO! In addition to Scott's remark, take care with tags. [tag:puzzle] has a giant "do not use" banner.

Comment: Prolog is a very different language from C or any other imperative language. The biggest mistake beginners make is taking what they know from their imperative language background and trying to map it to Prolog, even assuming that some syntactic/semantic elements work the same. Assume that none of them do. Prolog is a declarative language. Variables must begin with a capital letter. Prolog has *predicates* not *functions*, so they do not return a value. Predicates define relationships involving their arguments. They succeed or they fail (or possibly don't terminate, in the bad extreme).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is a very interesting Problem. I suppose you want a general solution -> one lever can move multiple mechanisms. In the case the problem is like yours, where one lever only controls one mechanism the solution is trivial. You just move every lever for the amount of time until the mechanism is at state zero.

But I want to provide a more general solution, so where one lever can move multiple mechanisms. But first a little bit math. Don't worry i'll end up doing an example too.

Lets define

[image]

as being n levers and

[image]

being m mechanisms. Then lets define every lever by a vector:

[image]

where [image] is the amount of steps [image] moves [image] forward.

For the mechanisms we define:

[image]

beeing the bias of the mechanisms -> so [image] is in initial state [image] and

[image]

being the amount of states for every mechanism. So now we can describe our whole system like this:

[image]

wher [image] is the amount of times we have to activate [image]. If we want to set all mechanisms to zero.  If you are not familiar with the [image][image] notation this just means that a%m = b%m.

[image]

can we rewritten as:

[image]

where k can be any natural number. So we can rewrite our system to an equation system:

[image]

[image]

[image]

prolog can solve for us such a equation system.
(there are different solutions to solve diophantine equation systems look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diophantine_equation)

Ok now lets make an example: let say we have two levers and three mechanisms with 4 states. The fist lever moves M1 one forward and M3 two forward. The second lever moves M2 one forward and M3 one forward. M1 is in State 2. M2 is in State 3. M3 is in State 3. So our equation system looks like this:

[image]

[image]

[image]

in prolog we can solve this with the clpfd libary.

```
?- [library(clpfd)].
```

and then solve like this:

```
?- X1+(-4)*K1+2 #= 0, 1*X2+(-4)*K2+3 #= 0, 2*X1+X2+(-4)*K3+3 #= 0,Vs = [X1,X2], Vs ins 0..100,label(Vs).
```

which gives us the solution

Vs = [2, 1]

-> so X1 = 2 and X2 = 1 which is correct. Prolog can give you more solutions.

Comment: Thanks that was really clear and helpful. You were right and ultimately i was looking for a solution for multiple levers controlling multiple mechanisms with different number of states. That's actually much more clever than my approach of testing every possible combinations.

Comment: Be aware that my prolog programm is also a bruteforce approach that tries out all possible solutions. if you are interested in a better way of solving the equation system you may start with this paper https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~wgilbert/Research/GilbertPathria.pdf which is dicussing how to solve diophantine equation systems